# Running Sqoop job on YARN using Oozie

Tags: hadoop-yarn, sqoop, oozie, hue

I've got a problem with running Sqoop job on YARN in Oozie using Hue. I want to download table from Oracle database and upload that table to HDFS. I've got multinode cluster consists of 4 nodes.

I want to run simple Sqoop statement:

```
import --options-file /tmp/oracle_dos.txt --table BD.BD_TABLE --target-dir /user/user1/files/user_temp_20160930_30 --m 1
```

Options file is located on local system on node number 1. Other nodes have no options file in /tmp/ dir. I created Oozie workflow with Sqoop job and tried to run it, but I got error:

```
3432 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Error while expanding arguments
java.lang.Exception: Unable to read options file: /tmp/oracle_dos.txt
```

The weirdest thing is that the job is sometimes ok, but sometimes fails. The log file gave me answer why - Oozie runs Sqoop jobs on YARN.

Resource Manager (which is component of YARN) decides which node will execute Sqoop job. When Resource Manager decided that Node 1 (which has options file on local file system) should execute job, everything is ok. But when RM decided that one of other 3 nodes should execute Sqoop job, it failed.

This is big problem for me, because I don't want to upload options file on every node (because what if I will have 1000 nodes?). So my question is - is there any way to tell Resource Manager which node it should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom file available for you oozie action on a node, it can be done by using `<file>` tag in your sqoop action, look at this [syntax](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html):

```
<workflow-app name="[WF-DEF-NAME]" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <action name="[NODE-NAME]">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <prepare>
               <delete path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
               <mkdir path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>[PROPERTY-NAME]</name>
                    <value>[PROPERTY-VALUE]</value>
                </property>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <command>[SQOOP-COMMAND]</command>
            <arg>[SQOOP-ARGUMENT]</arg>
            ...
            <file>[FILE-PATH]</file>
            ...
            <archive>[FILE-PATH]</archive>
            ...
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
        <error to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

Also read [this](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2.1_Adding_Files_and_Archives_for_the_Job):

> The file , archive elements make available, to map-reduce jobs, files
>   and archives. If the specified path is relative, it is assumed the
>   file or archiver are within the application directory, in the
>   corresponding sub-path. If the path is absolute, the file or archive
>   it is expected in the given absolute path.
>
> Files specified with the file element, will be symbolic links in the
>   home directory of the task.
>
> ...

So in simplest case you put your file `oracle_dos.txt` in your workflow directory, add element oracle_dos.txt in workflow.xml and change you command to something like this:

```
import --options-file ./oracle_dos.txt --table BD.BD_TABLE --target-dir /user/user1/files/user_temp_20160930_30 --m 1
```

In this case nevertheless your sqoop action is running on some randomly picked node in a cluster, oozie will copy `oracle_dos.txt` to this node and you can refer to it as to local file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is about file permissions. Try to put this file in /home/{user}.

Comment: This is not about file permission for sure. Options file is temporary located in /tmp/ folder and chmod is 777. The problem is that file is not located on every node, but only on node 1, but resource manager runs job on every node.